# How do I make abbreviations expand for minimal prefixes?

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion, abbreviations

I want to create abbreviation for a large word, say `configuration`.

Vim command works even if we type part of it. Example, `s[ubstitute]`.

When you type `s`, `su`, `sub`, `subs`, `subst`, `substi`, `substit`, etc., all these keywords work for the same command `substitute`.

Likewise, When I type `Conf` or `Confi` or `Config` or `Configu`, ...
It has to expand to the full word. The user has to decide what should be the minimum part. In this case, it is `Conf`.

Without writing function or multiple remappings, is there a way to make this work?

I tried this way

```
:abbr conf[iguration] configuration
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I tried this in all different modes like abbr, iabbr, imap, inoremap also. Didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand your problem: if you use `:iabbrev conf configuration` the full word will appear when you write `conf` so you fixed the minimum letters to write to trigger the abbreviation, right?

Comment: That's right. In case if I happen to type confi (an additional lettler, without typing a space and typing the next letter), still it has to expand. That's what I want. Since we have to deal with hundreds of words while typing, it might be difficult to type exact short part every time.

Comment: You should use dictionary completion. Abbreviations and mappings don't fit your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use abbreviations, I'm afraid you'll have to

- either define one abbreviation for each leading part.
- or to define a mapping on a trigger like `<tab>` (or whatever) that analyses what is before the cursor in order to expand the missing part. In the end, this is how snippets plugins are expanded (except they are much more advanced)

You can also define a dictionary file and use it to explicitly complete text on `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K` (-> `:h 'dictionary'`)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little function that may help you, because I don't think you can do otherwise:

```
function! s:ExpandAbbrev(word, start)

  let l:start = a:start

  while l:start < len(a:word)
    let l:tmp_abb = strpart(a:word, 0, l:start)
    let l:start += 1

    execute 'iabbrev '.l:tmp_abb.' '.a:word
  endwhile

endfunction
```

You pass the string you want abbreviations for and the minimal length to be expanded.

Example:

```
call <SID>ExpandAbbrev('Configuration', 3)
```

Will produce (result of `:iabbre`):

```
i  Configuratio  Configuration
i  Configurati   Configuration
i  Configurat    Configuration
i  Configura     Configuration
i  Configur      Configuration
i  Configu       Configuration
i  Config        Configuration
i  Confi         Configuration
i  Conf          Configuration
i  Con           Configuration
```

Comment: Please expand your answer. Will this function be automatically called when I type a word?

Comment: No, this function will create abbreviations. cf the `execute 'iabbrev ...'`